# DDD how to generate unique address in model without checking persistent layer?

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I have an Address model in my domain which has some complex logic for address generation (imagine similar to IBAN), but since the address is quite short there may be some collision to already existing addresses stored in database. Since there is an established practice that models should not access repositories how could this be accomplished? 
Should I make an instance in service layer and then check it against repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every domain use case is technically a service. When you need to add a new `Address`, just create the object then verify if something similar exists.

In your service you can use a query that will check if the address exists. If you want it to be a repository method, then it means `Address` is an entity. However, be aware that the uniqueness is a business constraint and maybe it shouldn't be hidden inside the repository. I prefer to be clearly expressed inside the `CreateAddress` use case.

There is a catch though, everything in your service needs to be idempotent. If the app crashes and the command is handled again we need to be able to detect if it's a duplicate operation. Meh.. it sounds complicated but it's not hard once you've done it once.

Personally, I have a 'uniques' storage (which happens to use the database to ensure the constraint) where I put a value like [object_type+unique_property] and if it exists it returns false, if not it adds it to the storage. It's generic enough to work with any entity and it's idempotent as well.

Comment: Do you mean that you woudl implement a domain service, let it be called `AddressFactory` which would use a `UniqueValueStore` under the hood to ensure uniqueness through db constraints? `UniqueValueStore` could expose an `add` method which would return true or false depending on if it could or not insert the value in the db according to the constraint.

Comment: That's the idea, but I would use the store directly in the handler - use case -  which creates the address.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it by many ways but it depends on business decision as there are always tradeoffs to be made.

Generally the simplest solution is to have a sort of `AddressGenerationService` that would trigger the `Address` generation, pick the result and query the repository to check if it exists. If not it returns the created `Address`, if yes it will pick the one returned by the query. This can be done also in the application layer (which is kind of use cases) instead of domain service, it depends on your particular architecture. You have to bear in mind that this is not a 100% bullet proof. Imagine that someone has generated the same address after you've checked and before you saved it. It will crash. You have to check with business how they would handle it